# md-hover-full not working on md-fab speed dial

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I followed the code from the material design demo, but had no luck getting full hover (hover over where buttons "should be" and the speed dial will open) to operate.....

my HTML

```
<md-content>
      <md-fab-speed-dial ng-hide='CreateCtrl.hidden' md-direction="left" md-open='CreateCtrl.isOpen' class="md-fling" ng-class="{ 'md-hover-full': CreateCtrl.hover}" ng-mouseenter='CreateCtrl.isOpen=true' ng-mouseleave='CreateCtrl.isOpen=false'>
        <md-fab-trigger>
          <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-primary">
            <md-icon class='material-icons'>menu</md-icon>
            <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom">Menu</md-tooltip>
          </md-button>
        </md-fab-trigger>
            <md-fab-actions>
                <md-button aria-label="add measure" class="md-accent md-fab md-raised md-mini" data-ng-click='addMeasure()'>
                    <md-icon class='material-icons'>add circle</md-icon>
                    <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom">Add Measure</md-tooltip>
                </md-button>
```

...

```
</md-fab-actions>
        </md-fab-speed-dial>
      </md-content>
```

my controller

```
angular.module('musiComp').controller('CreateCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', '$mdDialog', 'SongData' , function($scope, $routeParams, $location, $mdDialog, SongData) {
        var self = this;
        self.hidden = false;
        self.isOpen = false;
        self.hover = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `md-open='CreateCtrl.isOpen'` and remove the controller name ( you can't call it like it's a function ( `md-open='isOpen'` )

And `self.isOpen = false;` should be `$scope.isOpen = false;`

And I would also suggest to add `ng-cloak` to `<md-fab-speed-dial ng-cloak ...`